# UITableViewcontroller in UINavigationController ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableViewcontroller` as a rootviewcontroller for a `UINavigationController`. the `UITableViewcontroller` comes with a default edit button on the navigation bar.  i am trying to replace this edit button with the default back button that usually shows up in a navigation controller. How can I get the default back button in the tableviewcontroller?

Comment: backButton belongs to `UINavigationController`, not `UITableViewController`. And this button appears for free after push viewController to navigate back in navigationController's hierarchy. So, your question is incorrect or I can't understand, what do you mean.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. as you said, the back button should show up by default . i was able to get it when i used a uitableview. however, with tableviewcontroller it doesnt show up.i am not sure what mistake i am doing that is causing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back button shows up once you pushed another `UIViewController` onto the `UINavigationController`'s view controller stack! It's automatically added by `UINavigationController` and the title that it displays will be the `title` property of the former `UIViewController`.

Comment: thanks for the response. i have 3 level hierarchy of UIViewController . maybe i am going wrong somewhere in navigation through this multiple hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

i understood my mistake. i noticed that the navigation controller of the rootviewcontroller was null.

below code helped in eliminating this error.

```
UINavigationController *navCMsgs = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ntvc];
[navCMsgs setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self]]
```

however, i have to explicity unhide the navigation bar as the setting for my rootviewcontroller is hidden